# Yii2 - ActiveRecord to Array

Tags: yii2

Is there any way to convert `ActiveRecord` to an array in Yii2? I do know we can do that for `ActiveQuery`, for example `User::find()->asArray()->one();`, but can we convert `Model` to array when it is already fetched? I want to do that in `beforeSave()` method and store that array in cache.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From Yii2 [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-array) - use [`ArrayHelper::toArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#toArray()-detail):

```
$posts = Post::find()->limit(10)->all();
$data = ArrayHelper::toArray($posts, [
    'app\models\Post' => [
        'id',
        'title',
        // the key name in array result => property name
        'createTime' => 'created_at',
        // the key name in array result => anonymous function
        'length' => function ($post) {
            return strlen($post->content);
        },
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I would like to add that ActiveRecord also has a function `toArray()`, so `$model->toArray()` would also work for converting a single model after it is fetched.

Comment: @JelmerKeij  please post a proper related question well described so all the SO community can help you ..  and eventually comment me with the link of this question ..

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge it's not a question, it's extra information to point out that there's also the function `toArray()` you can use.

Comment: @JelmerKeij yes i kwon is function of activeRecord http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html

Answer (score 58):

Try this!

```
$model = Post::find($id)->limit(10)->asArray()->all();
$model = Post::find($id)->select('id,name as full')->asArray()->one();
$model = Post::find($id)->select('id,name as full')->asArray()->all();
$model = Post::find()->where(['slug'=>$slug])->asArray()->one();
```

Comment: this is a more yii2 way

Comment: This answer is far more optimal

Comment: TS noted: _But can we convert Model to Array **when it is already fetched**_. So, that answer is not very useful.

Comment: this should have been the selected answer

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and this information was already in the question.

Comment: This did not answer the question, yet was very helpfull.

Answer (score 6):

For one model it's sufficient to use a property `attributes`

```
$User = User::find()->one();
$user_as_array = $User->attributes;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new in Yii2, and it's a few difficult to make chains like `$model->search($request->get())->getModels()[0]->attributes` for example, for debug. Becouse all works via magic methods and IDE can't help.