# PHP: Map and join array of objects

Tags: php, yii2

Feels like it should be easy...

```
function flattenTags($t) {
  return ($t['name']);
}
$tags = array($Fan->getTags());
$flat_tags = array_map('self::flattenTags', $tags);
$string_tags = join(', ', $flat_tags);
```

where `tags` is an array of objects each with multiple properties.

Error:

```
Cannot use object of type yii\\db\\ActiveQuery as array
```

In JS this is a simple `array.map().join()`. Can't get it to work with PHP. Please help!

EDIT: do I need some kind of await like JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 - ActiveRecord to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125334/yii2-activerecord-to-array)

Comment: Not really, this is refering to ActiveRecord not ActiveQuery. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ActiveQuery has the same method, as the person asking the question there states right at the beginning … And you can easily go read up on it in the documentation, when in doubt. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery

Comment: Apolagies I'm brand new to PHP and Yii so I'm struggling a little, I don't have time to fully learn them from the docs. Is the line you're referring to `asArray()`?

Comment: When I try that I get `Call to a member function asArray() on array`. So I cannot call `asArray()` because it is already an array, but when passing it to map it's not an array. Any ideas?

Comment: Show _what exactly_ you tried, instead of paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
function flattenTags($t) {
  return ($t['name']);
}
$tags = $Fan->getTags()->all();
$flat_tags = array_map('self::flattenTags', $tags);
$string_tags = join(', ', $flat_tags);
```

The missing part was the `all()` command which converts a query into an array.